# How to grep for tags outside of a given tag

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to use grep to check if a file contains a `<script>` tag *outside* of the designated block: `{% block js %} ... {% endblock %}`.

If a file doesn't contain a `{% block page_content %}` element, it should be ignored (not all templates actually contain a `js` block).

The expression I have so far is:

```
grep -lrPz '(?s){% block (?!js).*? %}(?=.*?<script).*?{% endblock %}' src/
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

here is a file that should be detected:

```
{% block page_content %}
  {{ parent() }}
  <script> console.log("Hello world"); </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here are files that should not be detected:

```
{% block who_knows %}
  {{ parent() }}
  <script> console.log("Hello world"); </script>
{% endblock %}
```

---

```
{% block page_content %}
  {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
{% block js %}
  <script> console.log("Hello world"); </script>
{% endblock %}
```

---

```
{% block js %}
  <script> console.log("Hello world"); </script>
{% endblock %}
{% block page_content %}
  {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't point out what is wrong with your [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) solution, but another option involves setting the record separator in [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) to the opening and closing `js` tags and performing checks on the contents of each "record"

```
awk -v RS='\\{% block js %\\}|\\{% endblock %\\}' '/<script>[^<]*<\/script>/ &&
        (RT != "{% endblock %}" || prevRT != "{% block js %}"){bad++};
        /\{% block page_content %\}/{content++};
          {prevRT=RT};
          END{if(bad && content)print FILENAME":bad file"}' file.txt
```

Comment: With the minor tweak of `grep -lr "<script>" src/ | xargs --max-args=1 COMMAND_ABOVE` this is now working for me. Thanks 1_CR :)